# How can I get the raw text of an email in iOS Mail?

Tags: email, ios

Does Apple Mail under iOS support the ability to get the raw as-sent text of an email? Alternatively, is there a way to forward an email **as an attachment**?

I'd like to be able to report spam email to Spamcop.net, but I need all the headers and the raw source of the email, not just a copy of the rendered results.

Comment: Isn’t not showing these headers a security risk? How come no iOS clients show them?!

Comment: no, viewing raw text is not a security risk. In fact, with some effort, viewing the raw headers allows a recipient to ascertain where the email originated and if they should trust the email more or less.

Comment: @JGurtz: the comment said “isn’t NOT showing these headers a security risk?”.

Comment: Reading too fast! Indeed, NOT having the ability to show them can be a security risk

Comment: As of 2023 with iOS 17.0.3, this is still not possible. 

Mail.app on macOS is able to view raw message and email headers. 

Submit feedback if you need this: https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/

Answer (score 4):

Its 2021 and its still not possible with the built-in app! Nor with Outlook.

Thankfully Airmail does, even the free version. Open an email, tap the `...` at the bottom (not the top one as that one didnt work for me) and then `View Source`.

Note though that the free version will keep prompting you to purchase a subscription so its not a substitute. Also, and more importantly, the text size is quite small and the app doesn't allow you to zoom. You can copy the text if you must so there is that at least.

The second part to your question, sending email as attachment, Airmail does this as well.

When I tested sending as attachment from Microsoft's 365 (using Airmail) to GMail, I couldn't view the attachment in either built-in Mail app or through the web browser. I got a message that emaill could not be downloaded. When I added my GMail to Airmail, I was able to open the attachment.

Airmail to Outlook also worked in my tests.

Answer (score 3):

OK. I think I've got this figured out.

First, you need to have access to a gmail account. Great if the original email is already address to one. Otherwise you'll need to forward to a gmail address (or an account that's accessible via Gmail).

Next, open Gmail in a browser on your iOS device. I used Chrome, but that may not matter. Go to gmail.google.com and sign in to your account. It will likely take you to the mobile version. Scroll down the page and you should see **Mobile** | Older version | Desktop. You want **Desktop**.

Once there, open the email in question. Just under the address info for the email, you should see Reply, Reply all, Forward.... **Show original**. Click Show original and you should be golden.

Comment: Well, forwarding changes the header, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do so directly from iOS Mail app, but you can forward it to another address which the corresponding client supports **Show Original** option.

You can always do this sort of things with **Cydia tweaks**, but if your did not jailbreak your device, the way we said before is the only possible way.

**NOTE:** The best way is always waiting for the new versions. WWDC 2015 takes place in San Francisco in June 8-12, and they will introduce new versions of iOS and OS X.

Comment: Was there a tweak you had in mind that already existed?

Answer (score 0):

Log into iCloud via your browser. Go to email. Then “Show All Headers” will be an option in the message pane under the three dots.