# View email source in iOS Gmail app

Tags: ios, gmail, html

Is there a way to view the email source HTML in the iOS Gmail.app? `Show original` is available on desktop browsers. I haven't been able to find it on the app.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) A lot of operations available in the Gmail Web app are not available in the Gmail iOS (mobile) app. This is mainly to provide a decent user experience on a small screen sized device and the depending on relevance of feature.

Comment: it used to work as described here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/190198/46541, but need you to verify if it still works.

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t on the app. The app is optimised for better performance and compatibility. The only way to do it is to use `show original` on the web. And that can be done only on a computer because Google immediately moves to mobile mode when logging in from a phone.